# uEye camera unable to set custom resolution

Tags: c#, winforms, camera, camera-calibration

I'm getting an "NO_ACTIVE_IMG_MEM" error code when trying to set a custom resolution for a uEye camera:

```
statusRet = Camera.Memory.Allocate(1280, 720, 8);
if (statusRet != uEye.Defines.Status.Success)
{
 MessageBox.Show("Failed to allocate memory for 720p");
 Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

The code is from:

https://de.ids-imaging.com/programming-examples-details/ueye-net-text-on-bitmap-image.html

can be downloaded from:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rVWVetgvxVgOaxhmQuXISRpQwwL_PIZR

(original link requires registration).

The mem allocation snippet can be found in Form1.cs (resolution, color depth omitted):

```
statusRet = Camera.Memory.Allocate();
if (statusRet != uEye.Defines.Status.Success)
{
 MessageBox.Show("Allocate Memory failed");
 Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

How can I get a uEye camera to output images at a given resolution (4K causes low framerates)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AOI size to control the Resolution

```
Camera.Size.AOI.Set(388, 258, 1280, 1024);  (Resolution : 1280 X 1024)
```

and use "Timing" to set the Framerate

```
Camera.Timing.Framerate.Set(30);  (FPS : 30)
```